# how to select most frequent items from database?

Tags: c#, .net, sql

In the database there are column values which appear in multiple rows. The example rows are the following (in csv format):

```
    AFAB19476C2CEEEE101FFA45FD207BA8B6185B29,539EE0643AFC3A3BE3D20DC6BE7D5376DC536D34,9800,58,29,24,34,2
A801DA9B2F4116A7A1B14A13532B2177C7436C43,91850E4C50536D45C9CEAFE5FB5B3A87154EB754,9800,15,15,15,15,1
4C1E0B5387FB7FE19FC1ED682D0EB08249779180,9B17AE806C79437945F99C054B59A859D5639D11,9800,51,51,51,51,1
5B83A4BE4161497C62471BF133A4E1AD905D25F8,BFF4CED4F54F221A76714B311623398070847B26,9800,71,71,71,71,1
145145E49302ABBEEFF2797CAA8E122FFD3D5BFD,0C287F08E8E11DB4CF10CEB5801EBD61E7664FE4,9800,55,55,55,55,1
99C1F96461BC870574D002034F001BA3F96A9AB5,2EC4F3158764DC07D981008B3054B97809A0B048,Tujina,34,34,34,34,1
**CCB433630C735A8DA1B7828C10820B8CF91F25B9**,2C9C297BEF9CC1C0CF16A0559DE828FA0E226698,9817,339,169,137,202,2
BF2A7F0A9AD762B46A4423F76BF0479B9A72F163,336FB392EA4EF85EFE2563332CDE7D32FCE711B2,9800,34,34,34,34,1
...
**CCB433630C735A8DA1B7828C10820B8CF91F25B9**,C4015FE337F1EEFA1ECE4143D77F9627BEB9D358,9800,464,464,464,464,1
**CCB433630C735A8DA1B7828C10820B8CF91F25B9**,0EC08D78C637EF0A05E858B2BAC85C3EF05DF959,9800,73,73,73,73,1
```

In this example the value     **CCB433630C735A8DA1B7828C10820B8CF91F25B9** appears in three rows in combination with different values.

I am looking for a way to count in how many rows the value from the 1st column appears and then order the values by the number of rows that contain that value.

For example only the value from the first row was checked the query would be the following

```
SELECT COUNT (*) FROM records WHERE column_1 = 'AFAB19476C2CEEEE101FFA45FD207BA8B6185B29'
```

but instead of just first row the values from all rows have to be checked.

I would be very thankful if anyone of you could suggest an appropriate SQL query statement or a function to sort all the values from the first column by the number of repeatings.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT column_1, COUNT(*)
FROM records
GROUP BY column_1
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: +1 for not using the column position alias in the `order by` I like position alias for one off queries, but find they are less clear in production code. And use of `count(*)` to count the rows.

Answer (score 1):

The following will show you the counts of all the values in column1, ordered in ascending order:

```
select column_1, count(*)
from records
group by column_1
order by 2 asc
```

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
SELECT column_1, COUNT(column_2)
FROM records
GROUP BY column_1
ORDER BY COUNT(column_2) DESC
```